# Count number of visible listview items

Tags: javascript, jquery

I'm trying to count the number of list elements which don't have the class `.ui-screen-hidden` (ie. visible elements) from a jQuery autocomplete listview widget. I just can't seem to get it right though. At the moment, this list has 3 `li` elements, 2 of which have class `.ui-screen-hidden`. The following code outputs the total number of `li` elements (3). Any thoughts?

```
var elemsToSearch = $("#holderForListview ul li");
var i = 0;
$.each(elemsToSearch, function(index, elem) {
    if (!$(elem).hasClass("ui-screen-hidden")) {
        ++i;
    }
});
console.log(i); //3
```

I've also tried the following but it outputs zero:

```
console.log($("#holderForListview ul li:visible").length); //0
```

**EDIT:**

Here is example raw HTML being filtered:

```
<div id="holderForListview" class="myDataHolder">
    <ul data-enhanced="true" data-role="listview" data-inset="true" data-filter="true" data-filter-reveal="true" data-input="#name">
        <li data-filtertext="One 1"><a href="#">One</a></li>
        <li data-filtertext="Two 2"><a href="#">Two</a></li>
        <li data-filtertext="Three 3"><a href="#">Three</a></li>
    </ul>
</div>
```

Here is filtered HTML:

```
<div id="holderForListview" class="myDataHolder">
    <ul data-enhanced="true" data-role="listview" data-inset="true" data-filter="true" data-filter-reveal="true" data-input="#name">
        <li data-filtertext="One 1" class="ui-screen-hidden"><a href="#">One</a></li>
        <li data-filtertext="Two 2" class="ui-first-child ui-last-child"><a href="#">Two</a></li>
        <li data-filtertext="Three 3" class="ui-screen-hidden"><a href="#">Three</a></li>
    </ul>
</div>
```

Strangely, the output of `console.log($(elem));` inside the `$.each` function outputs 3 arrays, each containing one element:

```
[<li data-filtertext="One 1" class="ui-screen-hidden"><a href="#">One</a></li>]
[<li data-filtertext="Two 2" class="ui-first-child ui-last-child"><a href="#">Two</a></li>]
[<li data-filtertext="Three 3" class="ui-screen-hidden"><a href="#">Three</a></li>]
```

...not sure if that's relevant?

Comment: mind sharing an HTML snippet as well?

Comment: Thanks @SamuelBergström, I've added some HTML in my original post

Comment: Possibly you need to use [open](https://api.jqueryui.com/autocomplete/#event-open) event, to get count

Comment: Thanks @Arvind, but I'm not using jQuery UI, I'm using jQuery core and mobile. Do you think the code is being called before the listview is being updated??

Comment: @Brad, my concern is that while the ui is visible to user, only then you would be able to get proper count. Also element position matters, if the widget falls-off the view port that might also lead to such output. BTW, can you share relevant script as where and how the widget is shown to user?

Comment: @Arvind you're a genius! I nested my code inside `setTimeout(function(){ ... }, 2000);` and it works correctly! As this is all being called onPageLoad, it seems as though it's actually calling my function immediately prior to filtering the listview. Now to solve that one...

Answer (score 1):

the simpler variant of searching is:
    console.log($("#holderForListview ul li:not(.ui-screen-hidden)").length)

but your variants should work too. so, I guess some troubles with your html code

Comment: Thanks Denys, I've shared some html code too, maybe some clues in there?

Answer (score 0):

I looked at your code and created a fiddle for you. it should work so i think the only problem is that you forgot to wrap your jQuery code with **document ready**...

```
$(document).ready(function(){
    console.log($("#holderForListview ul li:not(.ui-screen-hidden)").length);
})
```

[JS Fiddle link](http://jsfiddle.net/chancet1982/jj10wdf7/)